# Add last path to redirect url using mod rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

i want to know the way to configure mod rewrite to achieve the following.

```
http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/.../pathn
```

should be redirected to.

```
http://example.com/static/path1/path2/path3/pathn
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod-alias (RedirectMatch) directive for this redirection :

```
RedirectMatch ^/path1/path2/path3/?$ http://example.com/static/path1/path2/path3
```

If the old uri is dynmic , you could use regex to handle it :

```
RedirectMatch ^/(path1/.+)$ http://example.com/static/$1
```

The first redirect will redirect **/path1/path2/path3** to **/static/path1/path2/path3** and the second Redirect will redirect **/path1/foo/bar** to **/static/foo/bar** .

If you want to use **mod-rewrite** , you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(path1/.+)$ http://example.com/static/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: in the output i need first three params and last param.

Comment: in the middle there can be any no.of paths.

Comment: Try : **RedirectMatch ^/(path1/[^/]+/[^/]+)/.+/([^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/static/$1/$2**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/.*/(.*)$  http://example.com/product/$1/$2/$3/$4
```